# Reference list is empty? Visual Studio, .Net Core. tried adding using system.web

Tags: c#, .net, image, visual-studio, reference

I'm trying to add a reference to `System.Web.Abstractions`, so I can use `HttpPostedFileBase` in my ViewModel.

Here is my viewModel

```
public class CreateCarVM
{
    public CarModel Car { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Basically `CarModel` just contains info about the car, and Images should be pictures of it. But I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpPostedFileBase' could not
>   be found

I tried adding using statements but it didn't work. Then I read that I need to add a reference, so I open my reference manager, and it's empty..

[image]

So now I don't know what to do...

Comment: You are looking at the tab for referencing other projects in your solution. Presumably there aren't any, hence it is blank.

Comment: @maccettura that was re: the OP's question as to why the UI shows "No items found".

Comment: OP, edit your question and show us the using statements you have tried

Comment: Please read the question before posting these... I said I've read those, and their solution is to add a reference but as you can see, there is none for me.

Comment: Same issue other than that I'm trying to add System.Data.SqlClient. All googling to this point suggests no answer other than that sometimes Visual Studio installations are just broken (in fact installing this one required me attempt to run the installer three times, see it crash, delete the temporary files and try again - next thing to try would have been reinstalling windows).

Obviously hoping that isn't the only answer for this situation. My version is community edition 2019, maybe OP should reference theirs in case it's also relevant?